# Determine ABI of installed app

Tags: applications

For a particular installed app (in my case, `com.android.chrome`), is there a way to tell which ABI is being used (e.g., `arm64-v8a`)?

I know I could launch the app and run `file` on `/proc/<PID>/exe` but I'm wondering if there's a way to do this by examining the app itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modern apps installed from Google Play Store consist of multiple APK files (also known as split APK files). If the app contains native `.so` files those files are usually packed per-ABI (e.g. `armeabi-v7a` `arm64-v8a` `x86` or `x86_64`) and only the matching ABI file is downloaded and installed.

Therefore for some apps you can check the installed ABI by listing all APK files that belong to an app:

```
adb shell pm path <packagename>
```

Example:

```
package:/data/app/.../com.example.app-SO6ebvL9yDViMlHkHQ6NPw==/base.apk
package:/data/app/.../com.example.app-SO6ebvL9yDViMlHkHQ6NPw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
package:/data/app/.../com.example.app-SO6ebvL9yDViMlHkHQ6NPw==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk
```

If the APK list contains an entry that ends with `arm64_v8a.apk` and no other APK file contains in it's file-name an other ABI name then you know that the `arm64_v8a` ABI version is installed and used.

Unfortunately this can only work for split APKs. And even for some split APK apps it doesn't work for an unknown reason - `com.android.chrome` is one of those apps that is a split app with platform dependent so files but none of the APK files have an indicator in the file-name which ABI is installed.

Comment: For universal APK, can it be generally detected by the device's SoC instead?

Comment: @AndrewT. Only if the universal APK is really universal. But some single APK apps do only contain libraries for a certain subset of ABIs, e.g. if an game is older it may only contain armv7a ABI or newer games may only contain arm64-v8a and if the app is designed not to be executed on an emulator x86 ABIs may missing.

Answer (score 4):

To add to @Robert's reply, if the application has no native libraries, it means it is platform independent, so you can get the ABI from `adb shell getprop ro.product.cpu.abi`.

In the other case, suppose you have a phone with `arm64-v8a` and `com.android.chrome` only has a native library for `armeabi-v7a`, you can run `adb shell pm dump <packagename> | grep primaryCpuAbi` and get the app's ABI.

Example:

```
$ adb shell pm dump com.android.chrome | grep primaryCpuAbi

    primaryCpuAbi=armeabi-v7a

$ adb shell pm dump com.example.platform.independent | grep primaryCpuAbi

    primaryCpuAbi=null
```

You can also try `adb shell pm dump <packagename> | grep -A 3 "Dexopt state:"`

Example `arm`:

```
Dexopt state:
  [com.example.nativelib]
    path: /data/app/~~ThisIsAnExampleAAAAAAA==/com.example.nativelib-ThisIsAnExampleAAAAAAA==/base.apk
      arm: [status=quicken] [reason=bg-dexopt]
```

Example `arm64`:

```
Dexopt state:
  [com.android.dialer]
    path: /system/product/priv-app/Dialer/Dialer.apk
      arm64: [status=speed-profile] [reason=bg-dexopt]
```

Comment: `pm dump com.android.chrome | grep primaryCpuAbi` shows *both* `arm64-v8a` and `armeabi-v7a`.  The process is 64-bit.